# Why does Spark application throw "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException"?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-spark, classpath

I am running a Spark application that uses a custom class. I am using Eclipse and Spark `(v 1.6.1 with hadoop2.6)`.

This class is part of a jar, and I added the jar to Eclipse `classpath`. However when the application runs I get the error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: myWorld.myClass.<init>(org.apache.spark.SparkConf)
```

---

Program:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true);
  //specify some Spark settings for conf
  /*...
    ...*/
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

The class, `myWorld.myClass.java` does not have the so called `init<>` method, and by design, not required to. So, not sure why `SparkConfig` requires it. :(

Comment: so called `init<>` function is a constructor. Has yout class a constructor myClass(SparkConf)? If not create it

Comment: For the same reason as always: version mismatch.

Comment: @chrylis, version mismatch? Could you please throw more light on this?

Comment: @Jens will try that now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spark-submit to run application you must provide it with classpath in command line and also exectuor classpath.

```
--driver-class-path your.jar --driver-java-options "-Dspark.executor.extraClassPath=your.jar"
```

Supplying whole directory instead of jar file works for me.